# Jquery Ajax Promise does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, promise

I'm making a app and I'm unable to fire a promise, I breaked the code to the a simple example that still does not work, I'm using EasyPHP...

```
ajaxDialog = function( destiny ) {
    // Promise to let me know when complete
    return $.ajax({
      url: destiny,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).promise();

  };

  teste = ajaxDialog('data.json');

  teste.done( function() { alert("sadasassa"); })
```

Comment: `ajaxDialog = $.getJSON`?

Comment: Its a function, right at the beginning of the code sample ;)

Comment: What does not work? Have you tried an error handler?

Comment: I know you declared it, but it looks too similar to the already existing [`$.getJSON` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Why not use that directly?

Comment: Don't ever post a question saying "it doesn't work" without explaining exactly what happened and any error messages, if there are no errors, please state so! Are you sure that you're not getting an error calling `promise()` ?

Comment: $.getJSON just points to $.ajax :)

Comment: I don't believe `data.json` is a valid URL for ajax.

Comment: @JuanMendes No, I dont get any messages, it simply dont do nothing :|

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Of course it is. Even `""` can be resolved to a valid url.

Comment: If it dont do nothing that means it does something right XD??

Comment: Try adding `teste.always(function(){alert(1)})` to see what happens

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira Side note: You don't have to return `$.ajax().promise()`. You can just return `$.ajax()`, since that function returns a promise.

Comment: @JasonP As @Bergi, explained, calling `promise()` gives you something that is a promise only, not a jqXHR, which is a good thing so that you're not passing around heavy objects

Comment: with current jQuery ajax you should not need to return `.promise()` return the ajax should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax is failing and going to the fail handler. If you do the following you will see an alert.

```
  // This does get called
  teste2.fail( function() { alert("sadasassa"); });
```

Here's a jfiddle that proves that if you do reach your server, it gets called http://jsfiddle.net/L6bJ2/367/

```
$(function() {

    ajaxDialog = function( destiny ) {
        // Promise to let me know when complete
        return $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/json/',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).promise();    
    };

    teste2 = ajaxDialog('data.json');    
    teste2.done( function() { alert("sadasassa"); });

});
```

Comment: I guess OP doesn't want that because it's *more* than a promise…

Comment: @Bergi  I was looking for some documentation on a `promise()` method of a `jqXHR` and I didn't find it, I thought that would be the problem

Comment: Jeffrey Way does it like I'm doing it and it works, I really dont understand, is there some url that I can try to make a fiddle out of this just to be sure its nothing related with EasyPHP?

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira Here's an example of using jsfiddle and XHR, use that to create something we can play with. http://jsfiddle.net/L6bJ2/6/

Comment: Yeah, I thought that at first too, but jQuery defines its `Promise` interface as "*objects that have a [`.promise()` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)*" :-) So it is indeed available on jqXHR objects as well

Comment: @JuanMendes It fires with fail, but how? data.json file is in the same directory

Comment: Okay it was EasyPHP fault, I knew it, I restarted it and it worked, oh God Why, thank you all!

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira Did you even sniff the  network to see if the ajax is working? That's the least you should do in this case. Like my code shows, it's not getting your XHR, one reason why you should always have error handlers

Comment: It is working and I did, but it was so simple that I was going crazy

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira If you had really looked, you would see that there was something wrong with the request, no?

Comment: The request works fine, I didn't changed nothing, I just restarted EasyPHP, it is working as I posted it. I know my english aint very good but I think i'm being very clear

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
when(ajaxDialog('data.json')).then(function() { alert("aaaa"); });
```

Comment: What would that change?

Comment: No luck, nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

Check if this would work:

```
return $.ajax({
  url: destiny,
  dataType: 'json',
}).promise(function(){alert("This is a test");});
```

I don't know what would that change but everything is worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

> a simple example that still does not work

The JavaScript works well. Probably your server does not work and does not return a [JSON](http://json.org/) document from the `data.json` url.

Use

```
teste.done( function() {
   alert("sadasassa");
}).fail( function(x, s, e) {
   alert(s+": "+e);
});
```

and debug with the `Networks` tab in your [browser devtools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) what is happening.